# Questions regarding package names and Interfaces

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Hello everyone I would like to know your preference regarding naming java packages. As in do you prefer `com.example.controllers` (since it contains a group of controllers) or `com.example.controller` ?

Also if you have an interface named Shape do you prefer to name it `IShape` or just `Shape`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on standard package names, it should be singular :

- `java.util.function` contains multiple functional interfaces.
- `java.util.stream` contains multiple Stream interfaces and classes.

Etc...